# Get channel category from channel with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How does one get the channel category of a channel in Discord.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up having to ask on the Discord.js Discord server for this, but oh well...

Turns out that you need to install from the master branch, or at least as of now (November 2017). When the new update is officially released, channel parents will be acessible with `channel.parent` as suggested by @Ovyerus and `channel.parentID`.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you [read the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=parent).

```
channel.parent;
```

Comment: I tried that, but it always just returns `undefined`, as with `channel.parentID`. That is, for both categorized and uncategorized channels.

Comment: Are you sure you're on the latest version?

Comment: does not work in python.  also i dont see this in the docs.